# Convert to string/text ruby

Tags: ruby, string, text

I'm using the following code to download a page through a POST request:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'
res = Net::HTTP.post_form(URI.parse('http://example.com'),{'post'=>'1'})
puts res.split("Date")
```

The URL I originally used has been replaced with example.com

It works great, but when I try to call split (last line) it returns an error:

`<main>': undefined method`split' for # (NoMethodError)

I'm new to ruby, so I'm confused about this error.

Comment: I'm not at a computer I can test things on at the moment so I can't test this (which is why I'm not putting it as an answer) but try puts res.to_s.split("Date")

Comment: It returns this: #<Net::HTTPOK:0x60cd7c>

Comment: Oh, that's right. Doing "to_s" on an object returns the name of the object and it's location in memory. Sigh. I need more coffee.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method you are calling returns a [HTTPResponse](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/classes/Net/HTTPResponse.html) object, so you need to leverage that object's methods to get what you want.  maybe something like:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'
res = Net::HTTP.post_form(URI.parse('http://example.com'),{'post'=>'1'})
puts res.body.split("Date")
```

Notice the body method.

Or, if you want to see all the data returned:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'
res = Net::HTTP.post_form(URI.parse('http://example.com'),{'post'=>'1'})
puts res.inspect
```

Hope this helps!